# Convert an ASN.1/DER encoded type to BIN format

Tags: cryptography, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509

How to convert a DER-encoded RSAPublicKey ASN.1 type string from a form of `hex-dump` (cert.hex) to `.BIN format`? (cert.bin) Preferably without installing  an OpenSSL.

I tried Windows utility **Certutil**, but it gives error: nssutil3.dll not found. When I put this nssutil3.dll into one folder with Certutil, it gives next error, missing further DLL, etc. Perhaps some changes in Windows, as I been used it successfully in the past.

Comment: DER is already a binary format. Its an ASN.1 encoding. PEM would be a different story. Just save it to a file and name it whatever you like. There's no need for OpenSSL.

Comment: To save it with .bin extension, that's all?

Comment: Why do you believe there is such a thing as a ".bin" format? The Certutil you are referencing is a Mozilla utility, not Microsoft.

Comment: No, its Microsoft tool [MS Certutil](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc732443.aspx).

Comment: @triwo - are you sure it's not [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/tools/NSS_Tools_certutil)? The "NSS" in nssutil3.dll very likely refers to [network security services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Security_Services), which is a set of libraries developed by Mozilla.

Comment: Take a look at [this post][1]. Use whatever extension you like (.bin or .cer).


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22584962/3245057

Comment: @neubert DLL is Mozilla one, yes, but I don't know why MS Certutil gives me such error. I find it easier just to open Certificate in Windows, then Details tab, copy Public key from there, paste it into HEX editor (as HEX data) and save it, that's all.